# Trasladar valor para un JavaFx Label del código a fichero JFXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

Tengo un ***JavaFX Label* con un texto multilínea** (he introducido un salto de línea: \n en el mismo).

**En el fichero FXML** está definido así:

```
<Rectangle
    fill="#efefef"
    height="320"
    layoutX="470"
    layoutY="25"
    stroke="grey"
    strokeType="INSIDE"
    width="160" />
    <Label fx:id="mi_label"
        alignment="CENTER"
        layoutX="485"
        layoutY="35"
        prefHeight="40"
        prefWidth="130">
        <font>
            <Font name="System" size="16" />
        </font>
    </Label>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la línea: `alignment="CENTER"` consigo que el Label se alinea al centro con respecto a el elemento que lo contiene, pero no su texto. Para ello, **en el código** debo introducir la siguiente instrucción (para que el texto aparezca centrado):

```
mi_label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Ahora se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la instrucción que quiero eliminar del código y especificar en el propio FXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución tocando la GUI con [*Scene Builder de Gluon*](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) que a veces sirve para resolver estas cosas.

La línea:

```
mi_label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

en el código de la clase Java, puede ser sustituida por:

```
textAlignment="CENTER"
```

en el **código FXML** del Label, que quedaría así:

```
<Label fx:id="mi_label"
    alignment="CENTER"
    layoutX="485"
    layoutY="35"
    prefHeight="40"
    prefWidth="130"
    textAlignment="CENTER">
    <font>
        <Font name="System" size="16" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalemente para el estilo visual de estos nodos es mejor usar CSS, el cual javafx implementa.

```
.label{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #44c767 5%, #5cbf2a 100%);
-fx-border-radius: 6px;
-fx-font-size: 12;
-fx-text-alignment: center; /*centrado del texto*/
-fx-alignment: CENTER; /* alineacion grafica*/
-fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Es una posible opción. Gracias Andy.